# How to play the intro of Fields Of Gold (Sting)

Tags: piano, beginner

I'm trying to play the introduction of Fields of Gold by Sting, but the first change that's needed on the right hand seems impossible.
I need to somehow put my right-hand's fingers on F#, A, D & E. They're too far away. How is it possible?

To see that this is what's required, you can see the Synthesia video tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/mLwnO0ESyaE?t=18), I'm referring to the 18th second of the video.

Every help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That shouldn't be a stretch with 1,2,4,5 unless you have very small hands.

Comment: That wouldn't be unless the previous notes were F#, A, B & D. The transition seems impossible and I don't have very small hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Hand position

The first thing I would look at is your hand position.

Since we generally play with our fingers toward the edges of the white keys, it's tempting to twist at the wrist to bring the thumb closer to the F#.

#### Ouch! position

[image: "Twisted" right hand]

Instead, shift your hand away from you. That will bring your thumb closer to the F# without pulling your other fingers away from the D and E. Depending on how arched your hand is, flattening out a bit might also help.

#### Ahhh... position

[image: Hand shifted away from body]

### Option 2: Left hand assist

Playing the bass line with left hand fingers 4 and 5 should leave your thumb free to play the F#. Again, you might shift your hand forward (away from you) rather than twisting.

[image: Left hand positioned to low note in right hand chord]

Comment: With short fingers, plan B works well - my ring finger plays D about  an inch from the back end of the the key.